# Round the time up to the nearest hour pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, time

Trying to round the observed time to the nearest hour

```
Example Data: 
observed_time = ['2020-02-20T17:54:00Z', '2020-02-20T18:54:00Z']

slice_begin_time=['2020-02-20T17:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T18:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:50:00Z']
slice_end_time=['2020-02-20T18:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T22:05:00Z']

### LIBS
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(observed_time))
for i in range(len(slice_begin_time)):
    s[s.between(pd.Timestamp(slice_begin_time[i]),pd.Timestamp(slice_end_time[i]))] == s.round(freq = 'H')
print(s)
```

I got the error Error: round() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'

I do want it in a series.

Comment: I think I might use rolling() or resample() not sure

Comment: I guess you need to use `.dt.round('1H')` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
observed_time = ['2020-02-20T17:54:00Z', '2020-02-20T18:54:00Z']

slice_begin_time=['2020-02-20T17:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T18:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:50:00Z']
slice_end_time=['2020-02-20T18:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T22:05:00Z']

def match(time):
    for i in range(len(slice_begin_time)):
        if pd.Timestamp(slice_begin_time[i]) <= time <= pd.Timestamp(slice_end_time[i]):
            return time.round('1H')
            break
    return time  # returns the input time in case nothing matches

s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(observed_time))
# apply map function match to the series elements    
s = s.map(match)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0   2020-02-20 18:00:00+00:00
1   2020-02-20 19:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

If you simply want to convert your time series to nearest hour, you can use:

```
s = s.dt.round('1H')
```